# C# Make a Toolbox Item Public for all forms

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding how do you make a toolbox item (in my case, a textbox) that is on a form (let's say form2) so you can code on it in another form (form 3).

I already tried making it with the modifiers making it public but that does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"code on it" is pretty vague, but if you just want to access it, you must drill down to it through the form it's on.  Textbox1 on form1 is referred to as form1.Textbox1 in code and then you can access all the properties on it.

A better coding style though is actually to create a getter and setter for it that returns a textbox.

```
`
public Textbox getTextbox()
{
    Textbox t = textbox1;
    Return t;
}`
```

something like that.  And you can write to it similarly.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the help!